# Simple Question about Induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, induction

let x be a natural number
i want to prove that f(x)=$x^2$.

suppose that f(x)=$x^2$,
f(0)=0 holds

we'll  prove that f(x)= $(x+1)^2$,

in the functional equation we have f(x-y)+f(x+y)=2f(x)+ stuff,
so i'll be using (x,1):

f(x+1)=2f(x)-f(x-1) + stuff

can i use f(x-1)=$(x-1)^2$ ?(since .f(x)=$x^2$)? and the number x-1 is smaller than x

Comment: As written, your question is completely unintelligible.  Please, try rewriting it with a little bit more thought -- and maybe some punctuation here and there so that it doesn't seem like one long sentence?  I apologize, but I really can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot leave a comment, so I will leave an answer. As stated above, your question is unintelligible. You say you want to "prove that $f(x)=x^2$". What is $f$? You mention a functional equation "$f(x-y)+f(x+y)=2f(x)$+stuff". What is "stuff"?

To get help, do the following:

- Clearly state the problem, including a proper statement of the functional equation.
- Use punctuation and preferably also TeX-formatting to facilitate reading.

Also, you should consider not using irrelevant tags. In what way is your question related to linear algebra?

Comment: yeah i got it now thanks